# InnoDb update deadlock

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, percona

I have a 10 millions rows innodb-table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t` text NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `key` (`key`),
  KEY `book_id` (`book_id`)
)
```

At the beginning, columns book_id and key are zero/empty, and then it filling with query:

```
update books set book_id='123213', `key`='SOME_VARCHAR' where book_id='0' limit 1
```

And sometimes I have hard traffic on site and deathlocks on this query. Is there any solution for this or advice? Or maybe I need two tables for this.

p.s. Percona MySQL 5.5 with buffer pool size 3G, log size 512M. Dedicated server with Ubuntu with 8Gb RAM.

Comment: I believe you meant **deadlock**. Deadlocks are normal, and you can't get rid of them. When you get a deadlock, MySQL denies one thread so the other one stops competing with it and finishes. The one that's denied will return an error. In case when you get an error that update / insert failed due to a deadlock, solution is to **repeat** the query. You show the user a message saying *Traffic is a little bit high so we can't deal with your request, please try again later* and a link / button that lets them repeat the query.

Comment: `book_id='ID'` will set `book_id` to `0`, since you are trying to put a string into an `INT`.  If that is not what you are really doing, fix the question.

Comment: @Mjh Thanks, deadlock, of course! I suppose, that there is some kind of design query error.

Comment: @RickJames book_id='INT'

Comment: The `text` is already filled in, and you are randomly picking one to give a `book_id` and `key`?  This does not make sense. Please describe the purpose in the `UPDATE`.

Comment: You are right! I have a 10 millions row table with pre-filled t (text) field. And Update looking for one row with book_id = 0.